# checking for number of selectors with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to see if there are any tags which have the class="red" in the code. I thought that this would work but it isn't. How would I do this?

```
if ($("[class='red']").length <=0)          /*if some of the entries are invalid (aka- have a red star)*/
        {
            alert('Some Entries are Invalid');
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just need

```
if ($(".red").length) {
    // have a least one tag with class red
}
```

This works because 0 is a falsey value; in the if expression if no tags with class red are found then length will be 0 and hence the if block will not be entered. If length has a value greater than 0 however (a truthy value), the if block will be entered.

Your original code doesn't work because the logic is the wrong way round (you'll be showing the alert if there are *no* tags with the class red) :)

Comment: @Joseph - Food for thought, it's not always best practice to do these "truthy/falsey" checks and instead you should be using explicit equals/not equals for code clarity:  `$('.red').length !== 0` or just `$('.red').length > 0`